# DRAW OVER OTHER app permission - condition to find 'this feature not available' devices

Tags: java, android, runtime, android-permissions

Hi I am working on a taxi driver application , in which I need to keep the driver online and app in background , I asked MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION as runtime permission . but in some devices (in Go edition , android 11) it shows 'feature not available' alert . I have read the [developer doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all#sysalert-go) and could find the reason . **now my requirement is to ask MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION  runtime permission alert to the devices which support this feature** . **Which condition should I use to differentiate it?**

Here is my code .

```
*if (//TODO Condition to check whether this feature is available on device?) {*  
                         if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(currentAct)) {
                             checkForOverlay(activity); //asking permission for popup
                         }

                }
```

Also I read draw over permission removed for Version Q and higher it will be granted to apps automatically [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#system_alert_autogrant) , but it is not granting automatically.

I tried `activityManager.isLowRamDevice()` , but I dont think it is right solution.

how can I resolve these issues.

Answer (score 2):

`Settings.canDrawOverlays(currentAct)` is a way to check if you can get draw overlay permission or not. In Go devices, it'll always return false as it uses excessive memory, so you simply cannot allow that permission in Go devices.

And for some special use cases, permission will be granted automatically regardless of an android version of the device. Explained here in detail as you mentioned - [Overlay permission changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#system_alert_autogrant)